# Curse of dimensionality: Data set with 1 million rows, max number of features can I have approximately?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, feature-selection

As the question entails, I would like to know as a rule of thumb, an upper limit on the number of features I could have for a data set with 1,000,000 rows/observations, before hitting the *curse of dimensionality*. If not a million observations, an answer with a rough estimate for the number of features for a data set with a specified size would be great too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The curse of dimensionality means that your intuition fails at a certain number of features. See [Average Distance of Random Points in a Unit Hypercube](https://martin-thoma.com/average-distance-of-points/) for some examples. It does not matter how many points you have.

For example, at around 100 dimensions every two points randomly sampled points are really close.

Comment: Interesting read. It is stated that the number of observations does play a role in alleviating this curse too: http://cleverowl.uk/2016/02/06/curse-of-dimensionality-explained/